# How do I use mutate in a data frame in R to update column based on value of a second column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In R I am trying to update one column in a data frame base on the value of the other column

So the dataframe is 2 columns 1st column s/b a number and second column is a date. For 3 specific dates, I need to update the exam column to a certain value. Data frame looks like this:

```
Exams  Year
NA     2009-12-01
NA     2010-01-01
NA     2010-02-01
```

and I want to change the NA to a specific value for these 3 dates

I have tried this:

```
library(dplyr)

ABVILE %>%
  mutate(Exams=replace(Exams, Year==2009-12-01, 1709.67)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

and tried putting the value I need to update it to as a variable too but it doesn't do the update either way and I don't get an error.

I expect it to be like this:

```
1709.67 2009-12-01
```

but I get this:

```
NA  2009-12-01.
```

Comment: If `ABVILE` is already a data frame, there's no need for `as.data.frame()` if the mutate is done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are (at least) two options using `dplyr` methods. Note that here I'm assuming your `Year` variable is a character vector. The first option uses an `ifelse` statement:

```
ABVILE %>%
  mutate(Exams = ifelse(Year == "2009-12-01", 1709.67, Exams)) %>%
  data.frame
```

`ifelse` takes a test clause and two return conditions (for if the clause is and is not met, respectively). That's an easy solution if you have only one test condition. If you have to string together many of them, then `dply` provides a nice function called `case_when`. Here's what that would look like:

```
ABVILE %>%
  mutate(Exams = case_when(Year == "2009-12-01" ~ 1709.67,
                           Year == "2010-01-01" ~ 999.999)) %>%
  data.frame
```

That's equivalent to

```
ABVILE %>%
  mutate(Exams = ifelse(Year == "2009-12-01", 1709.67,
                        ifelse(Year == "2010-01-01", 999.999, NA))) %>%
  data.frame
```

Obviously `case_when` is going to be a lot easier to deal with if you have lots of test conditions/assignments.